# Programmatically Update Date Stamp of ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, seo, filesystems, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

When adding new DB records to a ListView, I want to update the date/time stamp of the containing ASPX page for SEO purposes. Is this possible and how might I go about it?

**UPDATE:**

I found Touch for Windows, bu would still prefer any kind of clever hack just to do this programmatically:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Touch-for-Windows.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try setting the last-modified header of your response.

Comment: Any hints on how to leverage the API to achieve this?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer;since crawlers don't have access to the file system, I can only presume that a combination of sitemap and last-modified header will be acted upon. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple command line method would be

```
copy /b *.aspx +,,
```

Will update all of the matching files to the date and time when you execute the copy.